# Bitcoin-Qt Command line - adding private key - Mac OSX

Tags: bitcoin-core, mac, rpc-error-4

I recently created a custom Public key (with vanitygen) and i would like to add the corresponding private key to my bitcoin-Qt wallet client.  I have started bitcoin-Qt in server mode using:

`$ open Bitcoin-Qt.app --args -server`

And then issued the following commands, yet i cannot seem to successful add the private key, can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

```
$ curl --user bitcoinrpc --data-binary '{"method": "walletlock" }' http://127.0.0.1:8332/
Enter host password for user 'bitcoinrpc':
{"result":null,"error":null,"id":null}

$ curl --user bitcoinrpc --data-binary '{"method": "walletpassphrase", "params": ["************", 120] }' http://127.0.0.1:8332/
Enter host password for user 'bitcoinrpc':
{"result":null,"error":null,"id":null}

$ curl --user bitcoinrpc --data-binary '{"method": "walletpassphrase", "params": ["************", 120] }' http://127.0.0.1:8332/
Enter host password for user 'bitcoinrpc':
{"result":null,"error":{"code":-17,"message":"Error: Wallet is already unlocked."},"id":null}

$ curl --user bitcoinrpc --data-binary '{"method": "importprivkey", "params": ["************", "************"] }' http://127.0.0.1:8332/
Enter host password for user 'bitcoinrpc':
{"result":null,"error":{"code":-4,"message":"Error adding key to wallet"},"id":null}
```

So what happens is, when i try to decrypt my wallet it just says 'null' as a response.  At first i thought it wasn't actually decrypting, but if i lock it and then try twice to decrypt it, it tells me "Error: Wallet is already unlocked".

Great! so it is unlocked and we should be able to now add the private key, but i just get error code -4 ? what is error -4 ? how do i make this work??

Comment: I don't actually know, but I think (not sure, so I won't submit an answer) Error -4 means you've already added that private key.

Comment: I think you might be correct.  I deleted my wallet (there was nothing in it anyway, just getting started). and started fresh. I get all the way through these steps but instead of the error -4, now bitcoin-qt just crashes and uses 100% cpu when it try's to add that private key.

Comment: ah! ok, it doesn't crash, it just hangs for a while, eventually it does insert that key! Sweet.  I think your original answer is correct, you should make it an answer so i can mark you approved. thanks!

Comment: I too found out that importprivkey takes forever on OSX, around 5 minutes on my MBP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error -4 means that you've already added that private key. It might take a while to import because it's rescanning the whole blockchain for transactions involving that address.